# global variables store range slider value

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to using JavaScript and I have been researching how to store range slider values into global variables. I tried many different ways in attempt to display my global variable values and nothing has worked. Attached are snippets of my code.

```js
   var slider01 = document.getElementById("textInput01").value;
   var slider02 = document.getElementById("textInput02").value;
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
<b>Slider 1:</b><input type="range" name="rangeInput01" id="rangeInput01" step=".01" min="0" max=".1" onchange="textInput01.value=value">
Value: <output id="textInput01"></output><br />

<b>Slider 2:</b> <input type="range" name="rangeInput02" id="rangeInput02" step=".01" min="0" max=".1" onchange="textInput02.value=value">
Value: <output id="textInput02"></output><br />
</div>
                        
This is where I'm testing <span id="slider01"></span><br/>
This is where I'm testing <span id="slider02"></span>
```

Comment: You are not testing anything.

Comment: You need to set the HTML of `<span>` elements in `onchange`

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I don't think I'm quite following, do I have to set "onchange" equal to a function then and set values in my JS script?